# ms access counting occurences of a value in a column grouped by values in another column

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I'm updating a large existing project that was primarily created with the macro editors in Access. If i must convert it to vba and use SQl i'm open to that, but if possible i'd like to stick to keeping the existing structure as far as possible.
There is a series of Select queries. One primary query which calls the others to pull some data. I think these are extraneous and can be replaced by the right expression in the field of the column

this is an example of the type of table i'm pulling from

```
Table: Students
ID | Class   | Status
1  | English | Enrolled
2  | Math    | Enrolled
3  | English | Dropped
4  | History | Enrolled
5  | English | Dropped
6  | English | Dropped
7  | Math    | Dropped
```

what i would like the Select query to display is

```
Select Query: Class Report
    Class   | Enrolled | Dropped
    English |    1     |   3
    Math    |    1     |   1
    History |    1     |   0
```

What I'm having trouble with is the expression in the Enrolled Column to segregate the count to just a particular Class from the Students table when displaying it in the query.
The expressions i've tried for Enrolled are:

```
Enrolled: DCount("Students", "Status", "Status = 'Enrolled'")
```

This outputs the total of all students enrolled generally.i dont know if DCOUNT can pick out just the enrolled of particular classes

i've fiddled with the Count() function but i guess i'm just missing the understanding of what that field is expecting cause it hasn't worked at all.
again if i have to move to the VBA i will but i'd like to try and work this out in that Field. any help would be appreciated :)

*EDIT*
Here is what my Design view looks like right now with one of the answer suggestions
[image]

Works just as intended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select class, 
       sum(iif(Status = 'Enrolled', 1, 0)) as Enrolled,
       sum(iif(Status = 'Dropped', 1, 0)) as Dropped
from Students s
group by class;
```

Comment: does the Field box in the design view in a ms access Select query accept full SQL statements like that?

Comment: when i place the `sum(iif(Status = 'Enrolled', 1,0))` into the Field and set the Total field to expression. i get the same results as my DCOUNT run where it just counts every instance of Enrolled regardless of the class.

Comment: Create a new query, switch it to SQL View, paste in the text of the SQL Yogesh gave you, and run it.  Afterward you can switch the query to Design View in order to see how Access presents the `sum` expressions in the design grid columns.

Comment: Excellent advice. just got it working great. updated my question with the working design view so people can see what it looks like when applied that way.